# Need a solution to enter more then 100 PDF (or other) documents to one node

Tags: media, files

My client wants to be able to enter over 100 PDF and other documents to be downloaded from a single node. There will be several nodes like this each with their own linked files. Most of these are going to be less then 50, but there is a use case for over 100.

Right now they are using a field collection, as the nodes need to be restricted to area, have English and French description fields, and be able to be deactive.

The display of the nodes is ok, its the editing of the node. They are currently using field collections to gather the meta and file information. Then you hit a button to add another item and AJAX fires. It saves the node revision data for the file uploads and creates the next entry entity.  Once you get over 70 or so, IE pushes the returned JSON info out as a file for download.

This has to work in IE, as there are other systems the client uses that will only work in IE, and this can not be changed.

I have considered the media browser, but there are limits to that the client does not want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having all of the context here, my initial recommendation would be to consider integrating with a Digital Asset Manager (DAM), where your client can manage their documents much more efficiently, and select/attach which documents are part of individual nodes/entities.

In addition, most DAM solutions will serve your assets for you, so you are able to preserve disk space on the web application machine, while ensuring images are available and served up quickly via the DAM's CDN.

Comment: Also one issue with using just file fields (which it sounds like above) is that the node owns the files, instead of the node referencing media items which own the files.